# How to use sequence in a function in PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, sequence, procedure

1. In my schema, I have a reference number column in my settlement
   table with a null value of varchar2 type, that I want to update it continuously.
2. Then I've created a sequence called `ref_seq_num` using a built-in function.
3. I want to use it (`ref_seq_num`) within my function `get_ref_num` to update the sequence ref. number to my settlement table,
   which the return type also is varchar2 and I have a function like below

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ref_num RETURN settlement.ref_nr %TYPE IS
     v_ref_seq settlement.ref_nr%TYPE;
   BEGIN
     v_ref_seq := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')||LPAD(ref_seq_num.nextval, 8,'0');
     RETURN v_ref_seq; 
   END get_ref_num;
   ```

However, I bum into this error message `1/55 PLS-00302: component 'ref_nr' must be declared`. I also tried changing the data type to varchar2 and error message is `PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)` How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code, it seems that there's a table whose name is `SETTLEMENT`, but it doesn't contain the `REF_NR` column.

The following example shows how to do that:

```
SQL> create sequence ref_seq_num;

Sequence created.
```

A table that does contain the `REF_NR` column (which is then used in the function):

```
SQL> create table settlement (ref_nr varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

Your code, unmodified:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ref_num RETURN settlement.ref_nr %TYPE IS
  2    v_ref_seq settlement.ref_nr%TYPE;
  3  BEGIN
  4    v_ref_seq := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')||LPAD(ref_seq_num.nextval, 8,'0');
  5    RETURN v_ref_seq;
  6  END get_ref_num;
  7  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select get_ref_num from dual;

GET_REF_NUM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019050400000001

SQL>
```

Comment: As you corrected me, I found the typo that does not match the column name literally.

Comment: After I test it and it works. I wonder would the first ref number be increased by 1 when I update it to my ref. number column. e.g. become 2019050400000002 after testing it.

Comment: It would be increased every time when you fetch the next value from that sequence, regardless you do that in the function or run `select ref_seq_num.nextval from dual` elsewhere. In my opinion, that doesn't really matter as the sequence provides unique numbers, generally non-gapless (because of caching).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a column called `ref_nr` within `settlement` table, you code must work properly. I think the problem in the second case raises due to missing data precision part ( should be such as `varchar2(16)` ) for defining the variable as `v_ref_seq varchar2`. I would prefer using a numeric type such as `number` or `int` to hold the values for `ref_nr`, since they are all numeric, and this data type protects the data remain as numeric. Whenever you need to query you may use `to_char` function preventing exponential display( `select to_char(ref_nr) from settlement` ).

Moreover, if you use `Oracle 12c` version, you don't need to create such an extra function, just alter your table so that being sequence as your default for the column :

```
alter table settlement 
modify ref_nr default to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd')||lpad(ref_seq_num.nextval, 8,'0');
```